# Draw css columned text on HTML5 canvas

Tags: css, html, canvas

I have a div that contains text styled with css columns.

I want to "transfer" this text content on HTML5 canvas element considering all the styling applied to the text. Is it possible?

For now I fount that I only can draw some text in 2D context of the canvas using desired font style, but nothing about how to draw text with complicated layout on canvas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this is not a trivial thing to do.  I think it may also introduce some security/privacy concerns as well.

Regardless, I found this information that seemed to at least be on a track to having some, though not all, rendering capability:

[Rendering HTML elements to <canvas>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12652769/rendering-html-elements-to-canvas/12660867#12660867)

I had most success with the "html2canvas" one found here:
http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/documentation.html#how-it-works

And tried it, which works somewhat well in this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/UdESC/1/

External scripts:
http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/build/html2canvas.js

HTML:

```
<button id="exec">Exec</button>
<p>Input:</p>
<div id="abc">
    <p>This is a test</p>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Col1</td>
                <td>Col2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Col1 data sdafaksfhalsj</td>
                <td>Col2 data 3289rh982h</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<p>Output:</p>
<div id="output">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#abc {
    border: 1px solid #999;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#exec").click(function () {
        html2canvas($("#abc"), {
            onrendered: function(canvas) {
                // canvas is the final rendered <canvas> element
                $("#output").empty();
                $("#output").append(canvas);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, will consider the suggestions. But I don't think that html2canvas.js supports css columns.