# Shatter an element, sending pieces in random directions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I'm attempting to "shatter" an element - say, for example, an image - and send pieces of it flying in random directions. When the pieces reach their destination (i.e. *x* distance in pixels), they become smaller versions of the original image. jQuery UI's [explode](http://api.jqueryui.com/explode-effect/) effect is insufficient in that it doesn't randomize the direction, and it splits the pieces equally (i.e. must be divisible into a perfect square).

I found [this](http://jsfiddle.net/dNXVx/37/) JSFiddle, and I understand how it works - it wraps each letter of 'click here' in `<span>` tags and then animates sending them in different directions while scaling their font sizes and fading them out - but I have no idea how to adapt something like that to a single element/image whose content cannot be chopped up in that manner.

```
  $o.html($o.text().replace(/([\S])/g, "<span>$1</span>"));
  $o.css("position", "relative");
  $("span", $o).each(function(i) {
    var newTop = Math.floor(Math.random()*500)*((i%2)?1:-1);
    var newLeft = Math.floor(Math.random()*500)*((i%2)?1:-1);

    $(this).css({position: "relative",
      opacity: 1,
      fontSize: 12,
      top: 0,
      left: 0
    }).animate({
      opacity: 0,
      fontSize: 84,
      top: newTop,
      left:newLeft
    },1000);
  });
```

Any idea on how to go about accomplishing what I'm referring to? Not looking for solutions necessarily; just a helpful hand to guide me.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13894066/html-5-shattering-text-effect-and-re-assembling-text-back for inspiration.

Comment: Not quite what I was seeking but thank you nonetheless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going to have to render your elements to a canvas that you can then 'cut up' and explode. You can read about rendering to canvas here:

[Rendering HTML elements to <canvas>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12652769/rendering-html-elements-to-canvas)

Comment: html2canvas didn't properly replicate the elements even when I allowed document tainting. Doesn't appear as though what I'm seeking is currently possible. Or, if it is, it's so far above my head that I need to rethink my approach. Regardless, I appreciate the answer.

Answer (score 3):

I have been working on a small little JavaScript library split up an image: [Shatter.js](http://cdgugler.github.io/shatter.js/)

This will get you halfway there. You'll just need to add your own physics/gravity to make the resulting images explode in all directions.

There are a few examples listed on the bottom of the project page that show the image shattering in action.