# Creating duplicate elements at random positions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

Since it appears my previous question, located [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20931300/shatter-an-element-sending-pieces-in-random-directions), is technically infeasible for now (html2canvas will not properly render my elements as it only takes 'snapshots'), I am taking a different approach.

Essentially, when an object is clicked, I want it to disappear, and then multiple smaller versions of it are scattered across the screen at random. So, for simplicity's sake, take the image of a cat (cat.jpg): when clicked, it should seem like it explodes into three smaller cat.jpg images which are tossed around the screen. Meanwhile, the original cat.jpg is then hidden.

My (now fully functional) code:

```
  $('#cat').click(function() {
    $(this).hide();
    for (var j = 1; j <= 3; j++) {
      $('#content').append('<span><img class="cat" src="cat.jpg" /></span>');
    }
    $('#cat').css("position", "relative");
    $('img.cat').each(function(i) {
      var newTop = Math.floor(Math.random()*500)*((i%2)?1:-1);
      var newLeft = Math.floor(Math.random()*500)*((i%2)?1:-1);
      $(this).css({position: "relative",
        top: 0,
        left: 0
      }).animate({
        top: newTop,
        left:newLeft
      }, 1000);
    });
  });
```

I know that doesn't currently make them smaller, but if I get the duplication + random positioning done correctly, I can just make their size a factor of the current loop. Anyway, it semi-works, but is there a better or more elegant solution for this?

Edit: I updated my code with a version which actually works almost precisely how I'd like, but I am still seeking suggestions and improvements of any kind. I will award the answer to anyone who shows me a better method.

Comment: I go to bed but it seems to be a closure problem. I know it doesn't help u but it can help futur reader that will answer you right.

Comment: You're right, the code was messy, but I resolved the closure problem. Now the issue is that the .each loop doesn't execute asynchronously or something and is moving the last cat.jpg three times instead of just once. Thank you for the assistance though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

give it a try:

```
// $(document).ready(function(){ - i'm omitting this i suppose you know where to put the code.

var contW = $('#container').width();
var contH = $('#container').height();
var explode;

$('.holder').click(explode=function() {    
    for (var j = 1; j <= 3; j++){        
       var sourceX = (Math.random()*contW)%(contW>>1);
       var sourceY = (Math.random()*contH)%(contH>>1);
       var nTop = Math.floor((Math.random()*contW)%contW);
       var nLeft = Math.floor(((Math.random()*contH)%contH));
       var $child = $(this).clone();       

       $('#container').append($child);
       $child.css({ top:sourceX, left: sourceY })
           .animate({ top: nTop+'px', left:nLeft+'px' }, 200)
           .click(explode);
    }

    $(this).hide();
});
```

HTML little mod:

```
<div id="container" style="width:400px; height:500px; background-color:yellow;">
    <div class="holder style="absolute; "><img class="cat" 
        src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" 
        style="background-color:blue;" />
    </div>
</div>
```

JSFidle link here: http://jsfiddle.net/58YWM/8/

Let me know if it Rocks!

Regards.

Comment: Couldn't get it to work, but I think perhaps you're still updating it? Either way, truly appreciate the effort.

Comment: I think i forgot to update the Fidle so the code I posted here was not the one in Fidle, the code here in SO is the most recent. sorry.

Comment: Very nice! Thank you, your approach seems much cleaner.

Comment: to use pixels you must concat 'px'.

Comment: Very nice!! I had to switch in contW for contH in all places, to get it to work the way I wanted though.