# Leaflet image text label support

Tags: leaflet

is there anyway so i could export the text label using leaflet-image plugin.

I've tried many plugins other than leaflet-label bus it doesn't seems to work

thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to export text labels using the `leaflet-image` plugin?

No.

As stated on its [documentation](https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-image):

> This library **does not rasterize HTML** because **browsers cannot rasterize HTML**. Therefore, L.divIcon and other HTML-based features of a map, like zoom controls or legends, are not included in the output, because they are HTML.

While the statement about "browsers not being able to rasterize HTML" is [not entirely true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12652769/rendering-html-elements-to-canvas), the `leaflet-image` plugin does not implement (as of now) any method to rasterize HTML elements containing text. And text labels in Leaflet (unless stated otherwise) are HTML elements.

(On a side note, please be aware that asking a question with a "yes" or "no" answer might get you [literally "yes" or "no" for an answer](https://web.archive.org/web/20160527013035/http://homepage.ntlworld.com/jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/questions-with-yes-or-no-answers.html), and if this is not the answer you wanted, you should reformulate your question.)

Comment: Is there  any solution other than using leaflet image?

Comment: The only well-known solutions are the ones at http://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#printexport . There are other approaches, such as using a headless browser (such as phantomjs, or wkhtml2pdf), which are ways of automatically making screenshots of webpages. Those approaches will require more research and work on your part.