# getImageURI() not work from orgchart by google

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, google-visualization

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ei06039/b8bq4pvy/)

I created this fiddle but when try `getImageURI()` from chart (orgchart google charts) one error is generated.

> ERROR: "Uncaught TypeError: chart.getImageURI is not a function"

I need to generate an image or a PDF from orgchart created. Is it possible?

```
google.charts.load('current', {packages:["corechart","orgchart"]});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
    data.addColumn('string', 'Manager');
    data.addColumn('string', 'ToolTip');

    // For each orgchart box, provide the name, manager, and tooltip to show.
    data.addRows([
      [{v:'Mike', f:'Mike<div style="color:red; font-style:italic">President</div>'},
       '', 'The President'],
      [{v:'Jim', f:'Jim<div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Vice President</div>'},
       'Mike', 'VP'],
      ['Alice', 'Mike', ''],
      ['Bob', 'Jim', 'Bob Sponge'],
      ['Carol', 'Bob', '']
    ]);

    // Create the chart.
    var chart = new google.visualization.OrgChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
        $( "#chart_div2" ).append( '<img src="' + chart.getImageURI() + '">' );
    });
    // Draw the chart, setting the allowHtml option to true for the tooltips.
    chart.draw(data, {allowHtml:true});
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

similar to [Table Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/table), Org charts produce HTML `<table>` elements, rather than SVG

which is why `getImageURI` isn't listed in the [Methods](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/orgchart#methods) section for either chart

recommend using library to convert the HTML to Canvas ([`html2canvas.js`](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/index.html)),
which can then be saved as base64 string,
similar to `getImageURI`

see this answer, for a little more info on the topic...
[Rendering HTML elements to canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12660867/5090771)

Comment: hope this helps, found this fiddle as well [div to image](http://jsfiddle.net/8ypxW/3/)...

Answer (score 2):

try this code:

```
    function printImg() {
        html2canvas($('#chart_div').get(0)).then( function (canvas) {
            var image = convertCanvasToImage(canvas);
            var htmlToPrint = image.outerHTML ;
            newWin = window.open("");
            newWin.document.write(htmlToPrint);
            newWin.print();
            newWin.close();
        });
    }
```

Don't forget to include html2canvas.js