# PIXI.js - display pre-formatted text

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

We need to display the "Help" screen in our games, and it has to contain formatted text (weight, color) and pictures in it.

Is it possible to somehow render HTML (or any other markup language) into PIXI container so that it automatically uses correct text format and puts pictures in there?

We are looking for a working solution first before writing our own parser.

The language is JavaScript.

Comment: Why do you want to render the html to pixi container, instead of just showing it as normal html container?

Comment: With pixi.js directly I'm not sure, but there are several projects to render HTML in a canvas http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12652769/rendering-html-elements-to-canvas

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTMLText: https://github.com/pixijs/html-text

Here is an example of what it can do: https://pixijs.io/html-text/demo/