# Proper way to check if a URL is the result of a createObjectURL call?

Tags: javascript, typescript, revokeobjecturl

I have a situation where an image is being set by the user either to a URL or with bytes that is converted into a blob object URL. My understanding is that in order to prevent resource leaks, I should be freeing the blob object URLs when they are changed, but I'm not sure if I'm checking the type of the old URL correctly. Currently, the way I'm doing it is to just check if the url starts with `'blob:'`. Here is a toy example function that demonstrates that it indeed seems to work:

```
var url;

for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var oldurl = url;
    console.log('i = ' + i)
    if (i == 0 || i == 2 || i == 3) {
        console.log('Switching to Object URL')
        url = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(new Uint8Array(0),
                                           {type: 'image/png'}));
    } else {
        console.log('Switching to URL')
        url = 'https://example.com/example-image.png';
    }

    if (oldurl && oldurl.startsWith('blob:')) {
        console.log('Freeing old object url')
        URL.revokeObjectURL(oldurl);
    }
}
```

Is this the right way to do this? Is there a better way to do it?

I'll note that I've tried calling `URL.revokeObjectURL` on strings that are *not* object URLs and it seems to work fine, so it's also not clear to me how much it matters that I correctly determine whether the URL needs to be freed.

*Note*: This is a TypeScript script, but I think the question is equally valid in Javascript, so I've tagged with both.

Comment: Did you ever find another solution? I was thinking test if it includes `blob:`

Answer (score 0):

You are right, i think that currently there is no other way at all.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this the right way to do this?

**Yes**.

---

In more detail:

> Currently, the way I'm doing it is to just check if the url starts with `'blob:'`.
>
> Is this the right way to do this? Is there a better way to do it?

We can find out for sure by consulting the specification that defines how `URL.revokeObjectURL(url)` should work

<sub>(emphasis mine, and references to sub-instructions are inlined)</sub>

> **https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#dfn-revokeObjectURL**
>
> The `revokeObjectURL(url)` static method must run these steps:
>
> 1. Let `url record` be the result of parsing `url`.
> 2. **If `url record`’s scheme is not "`blob`", return.**
> 3. Let `origin` be the origin of `url record`.
> 4. Let `settings` be the [current settings object](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#current-settings-object).
> 5. **If `origin` is not same origin with `settings`’s origin, return.**
> 6. [Remove an entry](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#removeTheEntry) from the [Blob URL Store](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#BlobURLStore) for `url`:
>
>    1. Let store be the user agent’s blob URL store;
>    2. Let url string be the result of serializing url.
>    3. [Remove](https://infra.spec.whatwg.org/#map-remove) store `url string`.
>
>       1. Remove all entries from the `map` that match a given condition (i.e. equal `url`)
>       2. ...**or do nothing if none do.**

Additionally observe that the specification also notes that:

> This means that rather than throwing some kind of error, **attempting to revoke a URL that isn’t registered will silently fail**. User agents might display a message on the error console if this happens.

Therefore, we can conclude:

- If a URI's Scheme is `blob:`, or if a `string` URL starts with `blob:`, then it is [a *Blob URL*](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#blob-url).

  - ...and therefore it *may* be revoked by a script (on the same origin) calling `URL.revokeObjectURL(url)`.
- If `URL.revokeObjectURL(url)` is used with an invalid URL then *nothing bad will happen* (such as a thrown `Error` or other runtime exception). Examples of invalid URLs include:

  - non-`blob:` scheme URLs (due to step 2)
  - Different-origin URLs (due to step 5)
  - Already-revoked ObjectURLs (Due to step 6.3.2)
  - Syntactically valid, same-origin `blob:` URLs containing bogus UUIDs (Also due to step 6.3.2)

---

### Addendum: A Regular-Expression for Matching `blob:` Object URLs:

[The Web File API specification also prescribes a specific format](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#url-model) for `blob:` URIs, which means they can be matched by a regular-expression `RegExp` too (assuming the specification doesn't change):

> 1. Let `result` be the empty string.
> 2. Append the string "`blob:`" to `result`.
> 3. Let `settings` be the current settings object
> 4. Let `origin` be settings’s origin.
> 5. Let `serialized` be the ASCII serialization of origin.
> 6. If `serialized` is "null", set it to an implementation-defined value.
> 7. Append serialized to `result`.
> 8. Append `U+0024` SOLIDUS (/) to `result`.
> 9. Generate a UUID [RFC4122](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4122) as a string and append it to `result`.
> 10. Return `result`
>
> - An example of a blob URL that can be generated by this algorithm is `blob:https://example.org/40a5fb5a-d56d-4a33-b4e2-0acf6a8e5f64`.

Therefore the `RegExp` in JS would be this ([based on this RegExp to match HTTP Origin strings](https://gist.github.com/zaach/3099261)):

```
const blobObjectUrlRegex = /^blob:(?<origin>[\w\+]+:\/\/(?=.{1,254}(?::|$))(?:(?!\d|-)(?![a-z0-9\-]{1,62}-(?:\.|:|$))[a-z0-9\-]{1,63}\b(?!\.$)\.?)+(:\d+)?)\/(?<uuid>[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12})$/;

function isBlobOrObjectUrl( url ) {
    return ( typeof url === 'string' ) && blobObjectUrlRegex.test( url );
}
```

Demo:

```js
const objectUrlExample = 'blob:https://example.org/40a5fb5a-d56d-4a33-b4e2-0acf6a8e5f64';

const regex = /^blob:(?<origin>[\w\+]+:\/\/(?=.{1,254}(?::|$))(?:(?!\d|-)(?![a-z0-9\-]{1,62}-(?:\.|:|$))[a-z0-9\-]{1,63}\b(?!\.$)\.?)+(:\d+)?)\/(?<uuid>[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12})$/;

console.log( "Is \"%s\" an ObjectURL (aka Blob URL)? %o", objectUrlExample, regex.test( objectUrlExample ) ? "Yes" : "No" );

const nonObjectUrlExample = 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45941639/proper-way-to-check-if-a-url-is-the-result-of-a-createobjecturl-call';

console.log( "Is \"%s\" an ObjectURL (aka Blob URL)? %o", nonObjectUrlExample, regex.test( nonObjectUrlExample ) ? "Yes" : "No" );
```