# How to create a radio button list with nametags from a javascript array

Tags: javascript, html

I have been trying to create an HTML radio button list from a list of cable that the user inputs himself. The data goes into a CableList array, which contains a list of objects with many properties including the name.
I want to create that list of radio buttons with the length of the CableList, and assign the names to the radio buttons.

I am perfectly familiar with the for loop concepts, I am however not familiar with the appendchild method I have seen other people use. I am fairly new to HTML/Javascript and any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is just some of my ideas, however it does not work at all and I have no idea what to do from there.

```
function createRadioList(CableList){
    var c = document.getElementById("Canva");
    var ctx = c.getContext('2d');


    for (Cables in CableList) {
        var Cable = document.createElement('input');
        Cable.setAttribute('type', 'radio');
        Cable.setAttribute('name', 'choice');

        document.getElementById().appendChild(Cable);
    }

}
```

My expected results are simply a list of radio buttons with the name attributes of the cable list attached to them.

EDIT:
Thank you everyone for the reply. Here is my current HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--Created by: Philippe Gauthier 04/2019-->
<html>
<head>
    <script language="JavaScript" src="DrawCables.js"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript" src="drawingFunctions.js"></script>
</head>    
<body>

    <h2>Cable drawing function</h2>
    <canvas id = "Canva" width = "750" height="750"></canvas>
    <canvas id = "Legend" width = "250" height="750"></canvas>
    <form>
        <input type="radio" id="AllCables" > Show all cables<br>
        <script>createRadioList(CableList)</script>  
    </form> 
    <br>
    <!-- Rectangular switch -->
    Show cable names <input type="checkbox" id="CablenamesBox"><br>
    Show axis <input type="checkbox" id="AxisBox"><br>
    Show grid (NOT SETUP) <input type="checkbox" id="GridBox"><br>
    <script>MakeLegend()</script>
    <button onclick="InitializeDrawing()" type = "button">Draw Cables</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Relevant javascript code

```
function Singlecore(X,Y,totalradius,outerradius,innerradius,name){
    this.Center = [X,Y];
    this.TotalRadius = totalradius;
    this.ConductorOuterRadiusList = outerradius;
    this.ConductorInnerRadiusList = innerradius; 
    this.Type = "Singlecore";
    this.Name = name;
}

//Creates a PipeType cable type object
//The X and Y position of sub-singlecores are relative to the center of the main pipe
function Pipetype(X,Y,totalradius,name){
    this.InnerCablesList=[]
    this.Center = [X,Y];
    this.TotalRadius = totalradius;
    this.Type="Pipetype";
    this.Name=name
    for (var n=0;n<(arguments.length-4);n++){
        this.InnerCablesList=this.InnerCablesList.concat(arguments[n+4]);
    }
}
//Global, could be reorganised / changed

function CreateCableList(){
    //Creating objects and placing them in a list
    var C1 = new Singlecore(0,0,350,[300,250],[275,0],"Cable1");
    var C2 = new Singlecore(1000,2000,350,[300,250],[275,0],"Cable2");
    var C3 = new Singlecore(20,-2000,350,[300,250],[275,0],"Cable3");
    var C4 = new Pipetype(1000,-1000,100,"Cable4",new Singlecore(50,50,20,[15,5],[7,0]), new Singlecore(10,-5,15,[10,7],[8,0]));
    var C5 = new Singlecore(2000,-100,500,[300,250],[275,0],"Cable5");
    ListOfConductors = [C1,C2,C3,C4,C5];
    return ListOfConductors
}
```

I made a mistake in my original post... I am not trying to print it on my canvas but rather on me HTML. I would like to have a result like this(example taken from web):

```
<form action="">
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"> Male<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other"> Other
</form>
```

Rather than having 3 set radio buttons, Im trying to have a radio button for each cables in the cable list, and assign the respective names of the object.
As for the cables in mistake in the for loop, I just recently discovered the technique and I wanted to try it. I now understand that it only applies for objects and not arrays.

Comment: ***I am perfectly familiar with the for loop concepts,*** If `CableList` is an `Array`, then you aren't as familiar with for loop concepts as you think. `for/in` is for looping over `Objects`, not arrays. Additionally, you should never modify the DOM from within a loop as it can have dramatic performance effects. Also, we need to see all the relevant code in order to be able to answer you. Please add the relevant HTML as well.

Comment: `document.getElementById().appendChild(Cable);` Id of which tag?

Comment: Also, radiobuttons need a `value` attribute with a value that distinguishes it from the other buttons in its group.

Comment: You forgot to add `var` in your for loop `for(var Cables in CableList)`-

Comment: `document.getElementById().appendChild(Cable);` This cannot work since you did not pass an id to `getElementById()`. So `getElementById()` will return null.

Comment: Sorry about the mistake in my for loop, I normally do the 3 step for loop for(a;b;c) but I just discovered the new technique today and wanted to try it. I am not trying to print it on my canvas but rather in the HTML file.

Comment: @PhilippeGauthier I've updated my answer using the code you provided. Is that the desired output you want? If not, try to edit your question with the exact output and how you want it to work and leave a comment on my answer so I get notified.

Answer (score 1):

## Can't append HTML to canvas with JavaScript.

It's kind of unclear if you are trying to render the radio inputs inside a canvas. If so, that's not the way. Canvas doesn't accept rendering elements that way.

To solve your issue of generating radio inputs trough JavaScript, this is the way:

```
const container = document.querySelector("#Canva"),
      createRadioInputs = (items) => {
        items.forEach(i => {
            let input = document.createElement("input"),
                label = document.createElement("label");
            input.setAttribute("type", "radio");
            input.setAttribute("value", i);
            input.setAttribute("name", i);
            label.setAttribute("for", i);
            label.innerText = i;
            container.append(input);
            container.append(label);
        });
    }

createRadioInputs(["Item1", "Item2", "Item3", "Totally different item"]);
```

#### Why innerText instead of innerHTML?:

In this cases, since you only have to append text and not HTML, `innerText` provides better performance since `innerHTML` has to parse the string you provide. `innerText` does not.

If you *append* directly inside of a `<canvas>` tag with JavaScript it won't show up, use a `<div>` instead.

```html
<div id="Canva"></div>
```

If you want to try it out you can check [this working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k3llydev/emcdkh37/).

Also, someone already answered to *rendering HTML elements to canvas*, take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12660867/5568741), it may help you if you still need to render them into a canvas.

### EDIT:

My answer is adaptable to your code, but I'm going to think that you just don't know how to adapt it.

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k3llydev/d76f3wtv/) of the newer version of code in your question. Check it and tell me if that helps you. This is why you should've specified what you wanted since the beginning.

Comment: Hello, thank you again for the reply. I've been trying to place what you gave me into a function so I could call in it my HTML file but it keep giving me the same error: Expected ';' at the line "let Elements = CreateCableList(),", char 9. As you probably know I am new to javascript and HTML, thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 0):

Add `id` and `value` to tag, which should work then.

```
function createRadioList(cables) {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("Canva");

    for (var i = 0; i < cables.length; i++) {

        var radio = document.createElement('input');
        radio.setAttribute('id', 'cable_' + i);
        radio.setAttribute('type', 'radio');
        radio.setAttribute('name', 'choice');
        radio.setAttribute('value', cables[i])

        var label = document.createElement('label');
        label.setAttribute('for', 'radio_' + i);
        label.setAttribute('title', cables[i]);
        label.innerText = cables[i];

        canvas.appendChild(radio);
        canvas.appendChild(label);
    }

}

createRadioList(['a', 'b']);
```

[image]

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply. I made a small mistake in my original post. I am not trying to print the radio buttons on my canvas, but rather outside on the HTML file.